# float variable becomes infinity

Tags: c++, floating-point, eigen, point-cloud-library

I have a problem with this code.

I am acquiring a point cloud from a laser scanner, and with this method I want to compute a measure about how much the curvature change within a range window. To do that I'm trying to perform an inverse distance weighted average. The problem is that the variable `tot_distance`, a float initialized to 0 become infinity.

`pointRadiusSquaredDistance` is correctly filled by `radiusSearch` I have already checked.

```
{   
double range = 0.2;
double th = 1;
for (int i=0; i < point_cloud->points.size(); i++){
    std::vector<int> pointIdxRadiusSearch;
    std::vector<float> pointRadiusSquaredDistance;


    PointTypeFull p = point_cloud->points[i];
    Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Vector3f> norm_p = p.normal;
    pcl17::PointXYZ point(p.x, p.y, p.z);

    int n_points = search_tree->radiusSearch(point,range,pointIdxRadiusSearch,pointRadiusSquaredDistance);

    float tot_distance = 0;

    if (n_points > 0){
        for(int j=0; j<pointRadiusSquaredDistance.size(); j++){
                    tot_distance += 1/pointRadiusSquaredDistance[j];


        }


        Eigen::Vector3f av_grad = Eigen::Vector3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);

        for(int j=0; j<pointIdxRadiusSearch.size(); j++){
                float weight = (1/pointRadiusSquaredDistance[j])/tot_distance;

                Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Vector3f> norm_j = point_cloud->points[pointIdxRadiusSearch[j]].normal;
                Eigen::Vector3f diff = norm_p - norm_j;
                for (int w= 0; w<3; w++){
                    if (diff(w) < 0)
                            diff(w) = -1*diff(w);
                }
                av_grad += weight*diff;

        }
        float norm = av_grad.norm();

        if (norm>th)
            point_clud_curvature->push_back(p);

    }

}
```

Comment: One of the numbers in `pointRadiusSquaredDistance` may be `0.0f` which leads to a divide by zero, thereby Inf.

Comment: We don't like guessing about the data. Could you give us a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: Very small non-zero values of pointSquaredRadiusDistance[j] could result in infinite tot_distance. In IEEE 754 binary floating point arithmetic, if d is a subnormal double, 1/d can be infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you get tot_distance > 0.0 after,

```
if (n_points > 0){
    for(int j=0; j<pointRadiusSquaredDistance.size(); j++){
                tot_distance += 1/pointRadiusSquaredDistance[j];
    }
cout<<tot_distance; // should be > 0.0
```